# Issues Rendering PDF in iFrame Using base64

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use a base64 string as the source of an iFrame that represents a PDF. After about 1.7MB in file size, I have noticed that the iFrame stops rendering and just gives me a blank page. What is causing this and is there a way to get around it? The current tag for the iFrame is using data converted to bytes, then base64.

`<iframe id="ifrPdfViewer" src="data:application/pdf;base64,<%=hdnPdfData.Value%>" style="width: 100%; height: 91vh;"></iframe>`

The only browser I am concerned with is Chrome currently.